# Why do we need to use DAO and Repository in the same time on Android Project?

Tags: android, kotlin, design-patterns

I am working on a path project to learn Android deeply but I am really confuse about implemantation of dao and repository. What is the difference between dao and repository on android. Is repository a common pattern ?

https://github.com/basaransuleyman/KetgoMVVM

Answer (score 2):

Room is a layer over the `SQLite` database.

DAO forms the main component of the [Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room). We use queries to perform CRUD operations on the database(Insert,Update,Delete and Create). And `DAO` is the place, where we add such queries to perform operations. Inside a `DAO` we define methods.

On the other hand, a `repository` class is something that abstracts access to multiple databases. Although it is not part of the Architecture Component libraries, but is used as a best practice.

**Example**: Let say there is a `Person Database` , with a single table `Person`(known as [entity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Entity)).

For this example, we want to perform the following operations on the `Person` table:

1. Insertion
2. Update
3. Read

For all the operations, we need to write queries. Those queries are meant to be written under a `DAO` class, here `PersonDao`

```kotlin
@Dao
interface PersonDao {
   @Insert
   suspend fun insertPerson(person1 : PersonModel)

   @Update
   suspend fun updatePerson(persone1 : PersonModel)

   @Query(SELECT * FROM person)
   fun getAllPerson() : LivaData<List<PersonModel>>
}
```

Here, `PersonModel` is a model class to store the `Person` entity.
Next time, if we need to get the access to the `Person` table, we will implement the methods of the `PersonDao`. For example, like this:

```
     private val personDao : PersonDao
     private val personList : LiveData<List<PersonModel>>
     init{
       personList = personDao.getAllPerson()
     }
```

But wait, what if we have multiple database, we have to create a lot of `DAO` objects, which would make the code redundant, and prone to errors. So as to avoid that, we define a `Repository`.

```kotlin
class PersonRepository (private val personDao : PersonDao){
    
      suspend fun insertPerson(person1 : PersonModel) =
          personDao.insertPerson(person1)

      
      suspend fun updatePerson(person1 : PersonModel) =
          personDao.updatePerson(person1)
     
      
      fun getAllPerson() : LiveData<List<PersonModel>> = personDao.getAllPerson()

}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this in layman's terms!

Answer (score 0):

Repository is a common pattern. See https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html. A Data Access Object (DAO) defines the interface for how to perform CRUD operations on a particular entity. A Repository can have several DAOs.

See also https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data